# Why is there a VBA syntax error in this multi-line of code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line of code that is this long. VBE says it has syntax error. I checked the code and i'm pretty sure it should be fine. Did I exceed the limit?

```
Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 26) = "=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",0,IF(DTR!AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""Regular"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0,INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))+(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ") _
            +2*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*0.3*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3*1.3+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3*0.1),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""SNWH"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0 _
            ,0,(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5*1.3+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5*0.1),0)),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""Regular"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0 _
            ,INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))+(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3 _
            +(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*0.1),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""SNWH"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0,0,(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3*1.3 _
            +(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3*0.1),0))))"
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasted my time re-reading the code twice :/

Comment: The formula works in excel it's just that I needed to convert it to VBA due to a code that will paste special the formulas into values when a condition is met due to potential salary increases, then the autofill will only drag down constant values which is something I do not want. So I decided to replicate the string if autofill value is not a formula. Just to give a background

Comment: @Pac0 Sorry I tried to make it readable however as I split it to 6 lines already, it's one big formulas in 1 cell in Excel. It only returns 1 value.

Comment: That's actually just a simple syntax error - you cannot break a code line **within** a string literal

Comment: I understand that your excel formula is only one big line. But you can however split your VBA code into more line. As it is, I certainly do not want to go and check for small typos.

Comment: I see. However, when I paste the whole formula without the `space` + `underscore`, it will also have an error and I cannot type anything anymore

Comment: @Pac0 Noted i'll try to revise it to more lines.

Comment: Change your first line to be `... + 1 & ")" &  _` and your second line to be `"+2*(INDEX('P ...`, etc

Comment: you end the string at the end of line with a quote, add a _ to continue to next line, and concatenate the other line (and start your second line second string with quotes)

Comment: @YowE3K @Pac0 I see. I get what you mean now. I'll try it out I think that was my mistake. I was thinking it would be logical not to close the string because of the `space` + `underscore` did not think there was such a limitation to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following statement, which ensures that line breaks do not occur within string literals:

```
Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 26) = "=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",0,IF(DTR!AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""Regular"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0,INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))+(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")" & _
            "+2*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*0.3*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3*1.3+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3*0.1),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""SNWH"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0" & _
            ",0,(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5*1.3+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.5*0.1),0)),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""Regular"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0" & _
            ",INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))+(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*1.3" & _
            "+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*2*0.1),IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=""SNWH"",IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")=0,0,(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3+(DTR!Q" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3*1.3" & _
            "+(DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+1.3*DTR!S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8)*1.3*0.1),0))))"
```

I have no idea whether the code will actually run, but it at least gets around the syntax error.

Comment: It works. Thanks a bunch. Rarely work with strings more so with a special case

Comment: @MarcSantos P.S. That formula scares me!!  (There must be a simpler way to write it.)

Comment: That was the longest in my spreadsheet. It accounts for all the different rates for the holiday pay in our country. Different rates for regular working hours, holidays on a rest day, holidays on the night shift, and etc. There are many combinations to it. I could break it to several columns but I just felt I didn't need to add extra clutter outside the cell for no reason.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help been 3 weeks since I started learning VBA and you helped me a lot :D

Comment: That formula would benefit from being written in R1C1 notation - that would simplify things like `...DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "+DTR!R" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")...` so it was just `...DTR!RC16+DTR!RC18)...`.  (It's one of the few occasions where I would actually recommend reading up on R1C1 notation!!)

Comment: Yeah i'm familiar with it watched a guy in youtube talk about it although I was not able to try it out lol. Will read on it on my spare time